If I update a confluence page by sending an html body using atlassian-python-api, can the body include working html anchor tags?
I am writing a python script that creates an html body, then updates a confluence page with the html contents. For simplicity's sake, the html body can be divided into two sections: 1.) Overview and 2.) Details. The first html element of Overview should be a clickable link that navigates the user to the first html element of Details. I have implemented this as such
def generate_generic_html(...):
    anchor_tag = ...
    link = f'<h2><a href="#{anchor_tag}">{title} Overview</a></h2>'
    overview_html = ...
    overview_html = link + overview_html
    link_location = f'<h1 id="{anchor_tag}">{title} Details</h1>'
    details_html = ...'
    body_html = link_location + details_html
    return overview_html, body_html```

The html object are combined and posted to confluence via this method
status=confluence.update_page(pageID, confluencePage, html_body, parent_id=None, type='page', representation='storage', minor_edit=False)

The page successfully updates, and there is a clickable linked. For example: if anchor_tag = foo, I can click on "foo Overview". And my browsers tries to navigate to from https://org.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/%7Bspace%7D/pages/%7Bpage_id%7D/%7Bpage_name%7D to https://org.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/%7Bspace%7D/pages/%7Bpage_id%7D/%7Bpage_name%7D#foo-tag.
For testing purposes, I also wrote the html body to a local file. The anchor tags in the local file worked as expected.
I know that it is possible to add anchor tags to confluence using the UI, but I am looking for a way to add these tags programmatically.
Thank you!
